NextJS 14: MongoDB connection blocks the opening of the page
Sometimes, however, I want to open the page via the dashboard menu and nothing happens in the frontend. No loading screen etc. How can the problem be prevented so that the page is still loaded? The problem does not always occur, probably depending on the database connection. After a refresh with F5, everything works again as usual
I have the following code with which I display elements from the MongoDB:
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

async function Page() {
  const count = await countAccounts();

  return (
    <RootLayout>
      <p>{count}</p>
    </RootLayout>
  );
}

export default Page;

Under Services I have the following code:
export const countAccounts = async (search: string): Promise<number> => {
  await dbConnect();
  const query = buildSearchQuery(searchFields, search);
  const count = await Account.countDocuments(query).lean();
  return count;
};

And have a Mongoose model behind it to access the database:

const AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema<Account>(
  {
    id: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, index: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    isActive: { type: Boolean, default: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export const Account =
  mongoose.models.Account || mongoose.model("Account", AccountSchema);

Database connection:
import mongoose, { Connection } from "mongoose";

interface CachedMongoose {
  conn: null | Connection;
}

declare global {
  var mongoose: CachedMongoose;
}

const { MONGODB_URI } = process.env;

if (!MONGODB_URI) throw new Error("❌ MONGODB_URI is not defined.");

let cached = global.mongoose;

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongoose = { conn: null };
}

export const dbConnect = async () => {
  if (cached.conn) return cached.conn;
  await mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI);
  cached.conn = mongoose.connection;
  return cached.conn;
};

I have added force-dynamic in the hope that this will fix something.

Maybe https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming might help

Thank you for your answer! I have now added a loading screen. When I click on the page, the loading screen appears, but the data is not loaded. No error appears on the console on the server. However, the entire dashboard remains stuck in the loading screen. (Nothing can be seen on the browser log either)

It seems to be OK. I suggest you open Network panel in DevTools to confirm that the frontend has correctly processed API requests.

Let me mark the issue for you:
in your code's below portion

  async function Page() {
  const count = await countAccounts();


you need to pass a string as an argument of the countAccounts() function as you've declared it with a string parameter required in it

export const countAccounts = async (search: string): Promise
=> {

if you want to pass query parameters during fetching, you could build an API route that takes query parameters in it. The rest of the code seems okay and works on my computer. Happy coding..
